# Jquery function on UpdatePanel's trigger

Tags: jquery, asp.net, webforms, asp.net-ajax

I have

1. two UpdatePanels to display data from database.
2. one timer with interval set to 5 seconds.
3. one jQuery function to make content inside the UpdatePanel2 auto scroll.
   Plugin used: http://logicbox.net/jquery/simplyscroll/

The goal is to *check every 5 seconds to see if the data has changed* in the database then *automatically update panel1 and panel2* (if nothing changed then do nothing, I don't want to just refresh those panels every 5 seconds, because the panel2 is always scrolling so if it got refresh it will start scrolling again from beginning).

Problem is that, when the function `Timer1_Tick` gets triggered (every 5 seconds) it causes the page reload somehow and the jquery function no long works. The panel 2 data not scrolling any more, and when I call the jQuery function again using

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(
        UpdatePanel2, 
        UpdatePanel2.GetType(), 
        "ScrollMessage", "ScrollMessage();", true);`
```

like this, it will causes the data scroll from beginning, *although no data updated whatsoever*. So if you don't call jquery, it will not work, if you call it, it will do it from beginning.

Is there anyway to fix these issues

1. how to keep the jquery continue working (not reload) after the trigger event executed (partial post-back/reload page)?
2. how to trigger the UpdatePanel without partial post back?
3. any better way to check if data was changed in database?

JavaScript

```
function ScrollMessage() {
    $("#scroller-message").simplyScroll({ frameRate: 100 });
}
```

Markup

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" 
    Interval="5000" 
    OnTick="Timer1_Tick">
</asp:Timer>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Literal ID="ltl1" runat="server">
        </asp:Literal>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div id="scroller-message">
            <asp:Literal ID="ltl2" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Code behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        //*display data to ltl1 and ltl2*
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(
            UpdatePanel2, 
            UpdatePanel2.GetType(), 
            "ScrollMessage", "ScrollMessage();", true);
    }
}
protected void Timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //update panel1 if new data updated
    if (condition is good)
    {
        ltl1.Text = "new data";
    }

    //update panel2 if new data updated
    if (condition is good)
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(
            UpdatePanel2, 
            UpdatePanel2.GetType(), 
            "ScrollMessage", "ScrollMessage();", true);
        ltl2.Text = "new data";
    }
}
```

Comment: As a suggestion, did you consider to change the approach and not use UpdatePanels? Unless you need those for something else, it may be better to only use jquery to manipulate the data and html.

Comment: May be an sample or some articles would be helpful, please? My goal is that: constantly check if there is a change in the database table then refresh the page, that is it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to change your approach, leaving the updatepanels and using jquery instead, here are guidance steps to achieve it (you will have to complete/modify this sample to fulfill your needs):

As an alternative solution, you could place your database querying logic in a web service (maybe an .asmx file), wich checks if the content has been updated (for instance, you could have a datetime value storing the last time that record was written to).
If at least one value changed, return a JSON as the result of this web service.

```
[ScriptService]
public class CheckContentService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    private class Content
    {
        public string FirstContent { get; set; }
        public string SecondContent { get; set; }
    }

    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public string CheckIfContentChanged()
    {
        // retrieve your content from database
        // ...

        var c = new Content();

        if (firstContentChanged)
            c.FirstContent = updatedValue1;
        else
            c.FirstContent = ""; 
            // you could return empty to know that it didn't change, 
            // or you could have a boolean property in previous class and 
            // set it to true if content changed, but try not to return all content if it didnt change at all

        if (secondContentChanged)
            c.SecondContent = updatedValue2; 
        else
            c.SecondContent = "";        

        this.Context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        JavaScriptSerializer s = new JavaScriptSerializer();

        return s.Serialize(c);
    }
}
```

In your html, place two divs instead of your previous literals:

```
<div id="content1"></div>

<div id="content2"></div>
```

Then, in your javascript:

```
var checkForChanges = function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: "/myservice.asmx",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {

            if (data.FirstContent != "")
                $("#content1").html(data.FirstContent)

            if (data.SecondContent != "")
                $("#content2").html(data.SecondContent)

        },
        error: function () {
            console.log('Error.');
        }
    });
}

// check for changes every 5 seconds
setInterval(checkForChanges(), 5000);
```